# error load json data whit angular and google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-maps

I'll be very grateful who can help me with this line I've this:
I am trying to load this file json, but is not showing me json markers

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngResource"]);
app.controller("appController", function ($scope, $http) {

    var jsonData=[];
    $http.get('json/map-data.json').success(function (data) {
        jsonData = data.church;
    });
    var coordenadas={
        lat:4.600293,  
        lng:-74.175458
    }
    // recupero la posicion
    maPro = function(){
        var contain = document.getElementById('mapa');
        var position={
            center:coordenadas,
            zoom:10,   
        }
        $scope.map= new google.maps.Map(contain, position);
    }

    $.each(jsonData, function(key, data){
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                Title:data.nombre,
                position:latLng,
                animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        })      
    }) 
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', maPro);
})
```

i've got the following JSON file: is map-data.json

```
{
    "church":[

        {   "nombre":"ipuc brasilia",
            "pastor":"pastor brasilia",
            "telefono":"320 5559977",
            "lat":4.6309497,
            "lng":-74.1821257
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`$http.get('json/map-data.json').success(function (data) {
        jsonData = data;
    });`
```

this is a asyn request (Js dosen;t waits for the data and executes rest of the code..) So, while the js executes this

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key, data){
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, dat.lng)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                Title:data.nombre,
                position:latLng,
                animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        })      
    })
```

the `jsonData` haven't received the data and is undefined..

Keep this code inside success block of your request or use Promises to execute the code when data arrives.

Like

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngResource"]);
app.controller("appController", function ($scope, $http) {

    var jsonData=[];
    $http.get('json/map-data.json').success(function (data) {
        jsonData = data.church;

       var coordenadas={
        lat:4.600293,  
        lng:-74.175458
    }
    // recupero la posicion
    maPro = function(){
        var contain = document.getElementById('mapa');
        var position={
            center:coordenadas,
            zoom:10,   
        }
        $scope.map= new google.maps.Map(contain, position);
    }

    $.each(jsonData, function(key, data){
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, dat.lng)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                Title:data.nombre,
                position:latLng,
                animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
        })      
    }) 
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', maPro);
    });

})
```

Comment: hi i thit this, but dont work: var jsonData=[];
  $http.get('json/map-data.json').success(function (data) {
   jsonData = data;
   $.each(jsonData, function(key, data){
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng)
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     Title:data.nombre,
        position:latLng,
        animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    })   
   })
     });

Comment: @FERNANDOORTIZ any error in console ? `Ctrl+Shift+J` Put the entire code after $http inside success..

Comment: no, but the map work, fine, the only thing that does not work is the markers

Comment: hi, @atulquest93 i close de promise to the end, but nothing

Comment: The get request is getting data.. have you checked that ?

Comment: Are you getting data in `data.church` ?

Answer (score 0):

this its the code final and working

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngResource"]);
app.controller("appController", function ($scope, $http) {

    var coordenadas={
        lat:4.600293,  
        lng:-74.175458
    }

    maPro = function(){
        var contain = document.getElementById('mapa');
        var position={
            center:coordenadas,
            zoom:10,   
        }
        $scope.map= new google.maps.Map(contain, position);

        $http.get('json/map-data.json').success(function (responseData) {
            $scope.datos = responseData.iglesias;
            $.each($scope.datos, function(key, data){
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng)
                addMarker($scope.map, latLng)
            }) 
        })

    }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', maPro);

    addMarker = function(mapa, location){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:location,
            map: mapa   
        })
    }   

})
```